# Flexbox wrongly calculating width of items with text

Tags: css, text, flexbox

Here is my code https://jsfiddle.net/n4qpv91t/4/

HTML

```
<nav class="m-nav-main">
   <ul class="m-nav-main__menu">
      <li class="m-nav-main__item">
         <a href="#" class="m-nav-main__link">PLATFORM OF JOYSSS SAMPLETEXT</a>
      </li>
      <li class="m-nav-main__item">
         <a href="#" class="m-nav-main__link">LOREM DIMTURAGUA</a>
      </li>
      <li class="m-nav-main__item">
         <a href="#" class="m-nav-main__link">WORDS</a>
      </li>
      <li class="m-nav-main__item">
         <a href="#" class="m-nav-main__link">OFFRES SPECIALS OF WORLD</a>
      </li>
      <li class="m-nav-main__item">
         <a href="#" class="m-nav-main__link">LEARN FROM HOME</a>
      </li>
   </ul>
</nav>
```

CSS

```
.m-nav-main {
  width: 1000px;
}
.m-nav-main__menu {
    list-style: none;
    display: inline-flex;
    justify-content: flex-end;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

.m-nav-main__item {
    display: inline-block;
    border: solid 1px red;
}


.m-nav-main__link {
    display: flex;
    height: 50px;
    padding: 0 1rem;
    color: inherit;
    border: solid 1px green;
    align-items: center;
}
```

I have menu with text that breaks to 2nd line. Flexbox desnt get proper width of this text resulting in big empty spaces between text. I want those menu items to be as narrow as possible.  I use flex on links to have centered vertically text. Changing it to inline or anything doesnt make a change.

Comment: `width:min-content;` and `flex-basis:auto` https://jsfiddle.net/e42jLhxc/

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `flex: 1;` to `.m-nav-main__item`.

Comment: that makes them equal, not the width of text inside